# kotlin inner DSL that use infix functions to add more clarity

Tags: kotlin

```
kotlin 1.2.71
```

I have the following DSL I am writing and want to get it as close to this sample as possible:

```
android {
      compileSdkVersion 26
      buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
}
```

I am doing this using infix functions and lambda and receivers. Inside my DSL I have to use the `it` keyword otherwise I can't get the infix function to work. Just wondering, if there was a way to do this?

Another question: In my infix function do I need to use it as an extension function and prefix it with the keyboard Android i.e. `infix fun Android.buildToolsVersion(...)`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val androidConfig = android {
        it buildToolsVersion  "28.0.3"
        it compileSdkVersion 26
    }

    println(androidConfig.toConsolePrint)
}

private fun android(block: Android.(Android) -> Unit): Android {
    val android = Android()

    android.block(android)

    return android
}

class Android(var compileSdkVersion: Int = 0,
              var buildToolsVersion: String = "") {

    infix fun Android.buildToolsVersion(buildToolsVersion: String) {
        this.buildToolsVersion = buildToolsVersion
    }

    infix fun Android.compileSdkVersion(sdkVersion: Int) {
        compileSdkVersion = sdkVersion
    }
}

private val Android.toConsolePrint: String
    get() {
        return "compileSDK: $compileSdkVersion build tools: $buildToolsVersion"
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `Android` as both the receiver and the parameter? This gives the redundant option to use `this <fn> value` and `it <fn> value`. Anyway, for a Kotlin DSL a better option is to use `var` properties and the `prop = value` syntax.

Comment: I wanted to send it as a parameter as it would be the instance that would be sent to initialise the block using the `it` keyword. And used as part of the infix function

Comment: What's wrong with the `this` keyword, which you also made to refer to `Android`? Where's the benefit of the redundancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify: you do not need the `it` for the `infix` to work. You could also just have written `this` instead, e.g. `this compileSdkVersion 26`.

Note also that it rather suffices to just have the following in place:

```
fun android(block: Android.() -> Unit) = Android().apply(block)
class Android(var compileSdkVersion: Int = 0,
              var buildToolsVersion: String = "")
```

The usage then only differs by a `=` to what you have shown:

```
val androidConfig = android {
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
  compileSdkVersion = 26
}
```

But the benefit is way bigger: much less code to maintain ;-)

Regarding the other point you mentioned, that you need to supply extension functions. You didn't need to. It suffices to just place the `infix fun Android.buildToolsVersion` inside of the `class Android` without the `Android.` and it would have worked, e.g.:

```
class Android(var compileSdkVersion: Int = 0,
              var buildToolsVersion: String = "") {
  infix fun buildToolsVersion(buildToolsVersion: String) {
    this.buildToolsVersion = buildToolsVersion
  }
```

Now regarding `consolePrint`. That looks also rather complicated to me. What about the following instead inside the `class Android`?

```
fun toConsolePrint() = "compileSDK: $compileSdkVersion build tools: $buildToolsVersion"
```

That's what functions are actually used for... of course: if you do not like the brackets, you can still use your approach with the `get()`, but it sounds like a function, it acts like a function, so it probably also is a function ;-)

The complete sample with only difference being added `()` and `=`:

```
fun main() {
  val androidConfig = android {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion = 26
  }
  println(androidConfig.toConsolePrint())
}

fun android(block: Android.() -> Unit) = Android().apply(block)
class Android(var compileSdkVersion: Int = 0,
              var buildToolsVersion: String = "") {
  fun toConsolePrint() = "compileSDK: $compileSdkVersion build tools: $buildToolsVersion"
}
```